# can Xcode & iOS version affected on old project(which is created on Xcode 7.2 iOS 9.0 objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i dont know about Xcode 8,9 can it support objective c old functions and project?
my project is almost complete but some kind of function not supporting like `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`and etc in iOS 9.0 should i upgrade only iOS version or Xcode also Please anyone help me understand that iOS stuff.

thank in advance

Comment: Hi there!, Objective-C have binary stability which is backward compatible. The methods may be depreciated in iOS 10 but should be working. Moreover you should not see those depreciation if you set your iOS deployment target to lower OS version

Comment: Update settings and deal with depreciated functions.

Comment: @Shial thank for your reply should i upgrade Xcode or iOS version or both?

Comment: @Lumialxk thank, but how to update setting?

Comment: Just open your project with latest Xcode and look up warnings and errors.

Comment: iOS version on your phone? That is just a system. What you care is a deployment target. Update of Xcode will provide you newest SDK version and changes. Newest Libraries and other profits. But you can still use the same old stuff you used with your Objective-C code and support lower iOS versions

Comment: If you want to use UIDocumentBrowserViewController which is included in SDK for iOS 11.0+ you can't build your app for lower system versions.

Comment: Lumialxk & Shial so i only want to upgrade Xcode right?

Comment: if your phone is on iOS version lower than 11. you won't be able to deploy build to your phone if in your project you are going to use UIDocumentBrowserViewController. However, If you specify deployment target to lower system version you will be able to deploy to your phone but you won't be able to use this UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Comment: got it thank guys to give your worthy time to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to ship the app to the App Store, always keep your Xcode updated.  You cannot test iOS 11 using Xcode 8.x.

Also, [according to Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller) UIDocumentBrowserViewController is in iOS 11.

Comment: thank for warn before installing xcode 8.0 thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From Apple official site, for app store submission:

> Starting April 2018, all new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK, included in Xcode 9 or later. All new apps for iPhone, including universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X.

[Updated guideline of App store submission](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12202017a)

[Your app should be compatible with 64-bit support.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01242018d)